# Run the existing iPhone app in background from JSP page inside an UIWebView

Tags: iphone

I have a button in JSP page inside an UIWebView by pressing the button i want to run another 
existing iPhone native application in background only.Do anyone have a solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can't start any apps programatically. The only exception is if the desired app supports URL schemes. ([see docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html))
But it is not possible to launch it in background only.